# ELSE statement still executing even after IF is true

Tags: java, arrays

The following code allows the user to enter a football team and a score. If the football team the user entered matches a team already in the arraylist, then it executes the code.

**Why does the else statement still execute when the outer if-statement is true?** (i.e. the `itCounter` still increments even though the if-statement is executed). How do I ensure that it is no longer executed after the 'If' is executed?

```
int homeScore = 0;
int awayScore = 0;

int itCounter = 0;
boolean again = true;
while (again) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter name of Home team: ");
    final String homeName = input.next();
    Iterator<FootballClub> it = premierLeague.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if ((it.next().getClubName()).equals(homeName)) {
            System.out.println("Enter number of goals scored by " + homeName + ":");
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            homeScore = input2.nextInt();
            premierLeague.get(itCounter).setGoalsScored(homeScore);
            System.out.println("itCounter value = " + itCounter);
            again = false;
        } else {
            itCounter++;
            System.out.println("itCounter increased, value = " + itCounter);
        }
        if (itCounter == premierLeague.size()) {

            System.out.println("You must enter a valid team!");
            itCounter = 0;
            System.out.println("itCounter increased, value = " + itCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `if` statement are you referring to?

Comment: You must insert a break statement where you set again = false.

Comment: @sstan There is only one if-else statement!

Comment: @SamG: I can see that, but I just wanted to make sure you weren't referring to the 2nd standalone `if`, because what you are asking doesn't make sense.  You may *think* that both the `if` and `else` parts are executing, but they are not. Maybe you are just observing 2 different iterations of the `while` loop.

Comment: The `while` loop as-is is the same as `for (FootballClub club : premierLeague) { }`, and it will iterate **all** the clubs, entering the `else` clause for every club that is not `homeName`. That's as-coded, whether that's as-intended is up to you to decide.

Comment: please give us the code of `FootballClub` class, and `premierLeague` variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break out of the lookup-loop for the team:

```
boolean found = false;
Iterator<FootballClub> it = premierLeague.iterator();
int itCounter = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if ((it.next().getClubName()).equals(homeName)) {
        System.out.println("Enter number of goals scored by " + homeName + ":");
        // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        homeScore = input.nextInt();
        premierLeague.get(itCounter++).setGoalsScored(homeScore);
        again = false;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( ! found ){
    System.out.println("You must enter a valid team!");
}
```

Note 1: Take care to restart the loop searching for the team with all variables properly reset.

Note 2: Don't create another Scanner on the same input stream.